# Functionalism, its key concepts and social phenomena

Tags: sociology, social-epistemology, functionalism

I have a class test and have been instructed to find the following information and I have chosen the functionalism perspective and in particular Emile Durkheim as one of its key thinkers.

 State the perspective and its key thinker(s) 
 Outline the epistemological position(s) of the perspective.
 Choose any THREE concepts from the perspective and explain them.
 What main sociological phenomenon does the perspective focus on?

I am struggling with these questions as I feel social facts are important concepts but am not sure which to choose and if I should break them down for the 3 concepts. I feel the division of labour is very prominent and this relates to mechanical and organic solidarity and anomic division of labour. Collective conscience is also prominent (I feel, I may be wrong). I also feel that suicide and social currents are important but not sure how they would fit in. Any help with the above points would be greatly appreciated.